# Automatically Install Module/Extension in DNN (DotNetNuke)

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

Does anyone know if there is a way of **automatically installing an extension on DNN** using .net ?

It used to be possible using the infamous `Install.aspx` page, which has been removed for security reasons.

I've tried refactoring the code within `Install.aspx` so as to automate this, or even run it for a single module, but no luck. I've just got to the point where the zip has gets unpackaged, but what I really want is to know *which and how the tables in the Sql Server database get modified*.

I would appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite hard to find all the tables that get updated, as well as the data that gets put into them.

My solution was is to simply *call a copy of the installation page*, which can be done from, say, a desktop app. For some reason the original `Install.aspx` won't run if you add it to the DNN installation. Step by step:

1. Find the `Install.aspx` and `Install.aspx.cs` files. They are deleted after the first installation, but you can get them from the original download.
2. Make a copy of these two files and *rename* them, e.g. `MyInstall.aspx` and `MyInstall.aspx.cs`
3. In Visual Studio run the DNN installation *as a web site*, not as a web project.
4. Now the page `MyInstall` will work just as the `Install` did. You can pass the parameters in the url.
5. Before you call the page, you need to put your **module packages** into the corresponding folder e.g. for modules `install/module` of the DNN Installation. To create the module package use [Christoc's VS templates](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/DNNTemplates).